# Selling to Jews and Israel supporters

Tags: halal-haram

So I work as a digital marketer and I help e-commerce brands and business owners to increase the profits by helping them market their products etc so after the Palestine Israel conflict that happened two months ago there are some brands that says we are on Israel side or we are neutral but they sell halal stuff there is nothing haram is it permissible and halal for me to work with them because what I knew is the prophet peace be upon him used to have business,take loans,share profits with jews and unMuslims but he also had wars with them .the business im working with they don't donate to any Israel helping weapons or anything because they are just a small business is it halal for me to work with them note that I'm in a position where I'm not in school anymore and I have to make the things that I'm working on work because if I didn't my parents will force me to have college which I don't want to do because it's expensive on them and it doesn't serve me in this economy besides our financial situation is bad

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, ***engaging in business transactions with people of different faiths is generally allowed, as long as the products or services being offered are permissible (halal)***.

- **Holy Quran says:** "O my people, give full measure and weight justly, and defraud not men of their things, and act not corruptly in the land making mischief. What remains with Allah is better for you, if you are believers" (xi. 85-86).
  (In Quran, there is not a single verse that prohibits the dealings with non-muslims, but says to be just be everyone.)
- **The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) has set an example:** Indeed Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) had business dealings with Jews and non-Muslims during his time.

Narrated 'Aisha:
The Prophet purchased food grains from a Jew on credit and mortgaged his iron armor to him.

[ Sahih Bukhari Volume 3, Book 34, Number 282 ]

- **Uthman (ra) purchased Well from a Jew:**
  Uthman (ra) has purchased the half-time of the daily run time of the water well to 12.000 dirhams. The Jewish merchant, the owner of the other half, was weakened at the operating point because of the economic policy
  followed, and transferred his share to Uthman in exchange for
  8.000 dirhams.
  (Ahmed b. Hanbel, ts, p. 59; Buhari, ts, p. 59; Tirmizi, 1978, p. 625).

If the business you're working with doesn't contribute to activities that violate Islamic values things like,

- Monopoly.
- Speculative business.
- Interest based transactions.
- Selling the Decfected products.
- Transactions similar (in nature) to gambling.
- and they are not involved in supporting harmful actions,

it may be considered permissible.

However, If there are concerns, seek guidance from a knowledgeable Islamic scholar (Of your own school of thought: Malki,Shafi,Hanfi, Jafri etc) for a more personalized opinion.

Hope it helps.